# Can my code use a 'T' or 'const T &' specialization, whichever is available?

Tags: c++, templates

We are working with an inhouse library which features a `StringBuilder` class which is used to turn a list of `VariableValue` objects into a string. `VariableValue` objects can be constructed from arbitrary types (by specializing a `convertVariable` template function). Here's the code which describes the scenario:

```
struct VariableValue {
  // Construct a 'VariableValue' object, a variant type which can represent values of
  // one of four types: string, number (integer), boolean and floating point.
  explicit VariableValue( const std::string &serializedData );

  // Getters, typesafe; will yield an exception when calling the wrong getter.
  const std::string &asString() const;
  bool asBoolean() const;
  // ..  

  // Convert any VariableValue object into a string
  static std::string convertToString( const VariableValue &v );
};

// Template to be specialized so that user types can be casted into a
// VariableValue object
template <typename T>
VariableValue convertVariable( T v );

// Helper class to 'concatenate' multiple VariableValue objects into a single string.
class StringBuilder {
public:
  const std::string &result() const;

  template <class T>
  StringBuilder &operator<<( T v ) {
    return *this << convertVariable( v );
  }

private:
  std::ostringstream m_stream;
};

template <>
inline StringBuilder &StringBuilder::operator<<( const VariableValue &v ) {
  m_stream << VariableValue::convertToString( v );
  return *this;
}
```

This all woreds very well. Clients just had to provide an appropriate specialization for the `convertVariable` template (our library already provides plenty of specializations for various types) and then StringBuilder can be used. Almost.

The problem with this is that it doesn't work with types which are not copyable. All template functions take their argument by value. And in the case of the `convertVariable` template it's quite expensive to change the signature (because there are quite a lot of specializations). So even though I can make the `StringBuilder::operator<<` template take a `const T &`, this won't help much since the `convertVariable` instantiation will be just called with a `T` (since the reference-to-const part is stripped while deducing the template types). If I fix this by specifying the type explicitely, as in:

```
class StringBuilder {
public:
  // ...

  template <class T>
  StringBuilder &operator<<( const T &v ) {
    return *this << convertVariable<const T &>( v );
  }
};
```

The linker will complain because it no longer finds the old specializations (like e.g. `template <> VariableValue convertVariable( int )`) since it looks for specializations which take a reference-to-const.

Does anybody know how I can adjust the `StringBuilder` class so that I can pass non-copyable objects (that is, objects whose type neither allows copy construction nor copy assignment) to the `operator<<` function?

Comment: What it, for your non-copyable type Foo, you specialize `convertVariable` for `const Foo&` instead of `Foo`, and change `StringBuilder::operator<<` to take `const T&` always? As far as I can see, that should mean that the call to `convertVariable(v)` will pass by value if the user has provided a value specialization, and pass by reference if a reference specialization, so no need for a big disruptive change. I may have missed something.

Comment: @Steve Jessop: Unfortunately not; it seems that my compiler (MSVC9) immediately bails out when it sees that `convertVariable` takes a T by value. Implementing your suggestion bails out when calling `convertVariable` from within `operator<<`. I can fix this by calling `convertVariable` as shown in my second code example (explicitely specifying `const T &` as the type to use) - but doing so breaks all the existing `convertVariable` specializations (e.g. there is no `const int &` specialization).

Comment: ah, OK. Yes, it chooses the "wrong" specialization to try to call. As icecrime says, overloads are the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not quite sure my answer will be of any help, but it's worth trying. From your post, I tend to think that the appropriate solution is to change the signature of `convertVariable`. You say that this is expensive because there are a lot of specialization, but I think it could actually be free depending on the way you chose to 'specialize'.

This [article](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill17.htm) offers a nice guideline for these kind of things :

> Moral #1: If you want to customize a
>   function base template and want that
>   customization to participate in
>   overload resolution (or, to always be
>   used in the case of exact match), make
>   it a plain old function, not a
>   specialization. And, if you do provide
>   overloads, avoid also providing
>   specializations.
>
> [...]
>
> For another thing, **function template
>   specializations don't overload**. This
>   means that any specializations you
>   write will not affect which template
>   gets used, which runs counter to what
>   most people would intuitively expect.
>   **After all, if you had written a
>   nontemplate function with the
>   identical signature instead of a
>   function template specialization, the
>   nontemplate function would always be
>   selected because it's always
>   considered to be a better match than a
>   template**.

Indeed, instead of specializing for a type `UncopyableClass`, you could very well use overloading :

```
VariableValue convertVariable( const UncopyableClass &t ) { /* ... */ }
```

It's not a specialization but an overload, and it should work exactly as expected. Note however that `StringBuilder::operator<<` must take a const reference parameter.

Comment: +1: Nice! This seems to work; it didn't occur to me that you could *overload* a `convertVariable` function instead of specialization a template with the same name. Knowing this, I probably could've used overloading all the time. The only downside of this approach is that clients will have to know whether to specialize the `convertVariable` template, or whether to overload the `convertVariable` function.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any advantage into using this class versus simply using the `std::ostream` interface.

The soundest advise I have would be the dump the class and its bugs (`std::string const& str() const` for example) and simply go ahead with the stream class by overloading `operator<<` appropriately for those classes that need streaming.

Comment: Note that the `StringBuilder` class is actually implemented in terms of `std::ostringstream`. We don't use `std::ostream` directly since there are quite a lot of `convertVariable` specializations for which no `operator<<` overload (for use with `std::ostream`) is available. That side, I think it's actually quite nice not to inherit `std::ostream` but just reuse (and expose!) the interface we need.